# Pop multiple items from the beginning and end of a list

Tags: python, arrays, list

Suppose I have a list of items like this:

```
mylist=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
```

I want to pop two items from the left (i.e. `a` and `b`) and two items from the right (i.e. `h`,`i`). I want the most **concise an clean** way to do this. I could do it this way myself:

```
for x in range(2):
    mylist.pop()
    mylist.pop(0)
```

Any other alternatives?

Comment: If you have enough RAM, use list slicing.

Comment: Are you using a [`collections.deque()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) here instead of a list? Because *that makes a huge difference* from using the plain `list` type! There is *no* `list.popleft()` method, in the standard library only the `deque` object has that method.

Comment: Would it not be possible to use `.pop((len(yourArray)-1))` and so on?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

From a performance point of view:

- `mylist = mylist[2:-2]` and `del mylist[:2];del mylist[-2:]` are equivalent
- they are around 3 times faster than the first solution `for _ in range(2): mylist.pop(0); mylist.pop()`

**Code**

```
iterations = 1000000
print timeit.timeit('''mylist=range(9)\nfor _ in range(2): mylist.pop(0); mylist.pop()''', number=iterations)/iterations
print timeit.timeit('''mylist=range(9)\nmylist = mylist[2:-2]''', number=iterations)/iterations
print timeit.timeit('''mylist=range(9)\ndel mylist[:2];del mylist[-2:]''', number=iterations)/iterations
```

**output**

1.07710313797e-06

3.44465017319e-07

3.49956989288e-07

Answer (score 16):

You could slice out a new list, keeping the old list as is:

```
mylist=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
newlist = mylist[2:-2]
```

`newlist` now returns:

```
['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

You can overwrite the reference to the old list too:

```
mylist = mylist[2:-2]
```

Both of the above approaches will use more memory than the below.

What you're attempting to do yourself is memory friendly, with the downside that it mutates your old list, but `popleft` is not available for lists in Python, it's a method of the `collections.deque` object.

This works well in Python 3:

```
for x in range(2):
    mylist.pop(0)
    mylist.pop()
```

In Python 2, use xrange and pop only:

```
for _ in xrange(2):
    mylist.pop(0)
    mylist.pop()
```

Fastest way to delete as Martijn suggests, (this only deletes the list's reference to the items, not necessarily the items themselves):

```
del mylist[:2]
del mylist[-2:]
```

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to retain the values, you could delete the indices:

```
del myList[-2:], myList[:2]
```

This does still require that all remaining items are moved up to spots in the list. Two `.popleft()` calls do require this too, but at least now the list object can handle the moves *in one step*.

No new list object is created.

Demo:

```
>>> myList = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
>>> del myList[-2:], myList[:2]
>>> myList
['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

However, from your use of `popleft` I strongly suspect you are, instead, working with a [`collections.dequeue()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) instead. If so, *stick to using `popleft()`, as that is far more efficient than slicing or `del` on a list object.

Comment: How does this compare in terms of memory usage to slicing?

Comment: @wnnmaw: no new list object is created; so memory wise this is more efficient than slicing. You'll need a big list object for that to make a difference, however.

Comment: Why do you need the  `, myList[:2]`  part? Does that actually do something?

Comment: @holroy: the question asks to remove the first and last two elements of the list. Without the `myList[:2]` part you'd not be removing the first two elements.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yeah, of course... Had forgotten that part of the question, as I was looking to remove just the two first elements! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To me, this is the prettiest way to do it using a list comprehension:

```
>> mylist=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
>> newlist1 = [mylist.pop(0) for idx in range(2)]
>> newlist2 = [mylist.pop() for idx in range(2)]
```

That will pull the first two elements from the beginning and the last two elements from the end of the list. The remaining items stay in the list.

Comment: If you need the first or last two you need to use range(2) instead of range(1). Range(1) will only pop one, range(n) will pop n items.

Comment: You're right. I fixed the example. I'm not sure why I didn't notice that before.

Answer (score 3):

First 2 elements: `myList[:2]`
Last 2 elements: `mylist[-2:]`

So `myList[2:-2]`

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o']

new_list = [mylist.pop(0) for _ in range(6) if len(mylist) > 0]

>>> new_list
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

new_list = [mylist.pop(0) for _ in range(6) if len(mylist) > 0]
>>> new_list
['g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']

new_list = [mylist.pop(0) for _ in range(6) if len(mylist) > 0]
>>> new_list
['m', 'n', 'o']
```

Comment: Please add further details explaining how this code resolves the question being asked.

Answer (score -2):

**[Python3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132)** has something cool, similar to rest in JS (but a pain if you need to pop out a lot of stuff)

```
mylist=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
_, _, *mylist, _, _ = mylist
mylist == ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']  # true
```